# Can't find stdAfx.h

Tags: .net

The .NET project I have has suddenly started giving me the message:
fatal error C1093: API call 'ImportFile' failed '0x80070003' : ErrorMessage: The system cannot find the path specified.

When I look at the code it is pointing to, I see:

```
  #include "stdAfx.h"
```

That file hasn't gone any where.  It is still in my project.  Why would .Net suddenly not be able to find it?  Did I screw up the search paths somehow?  If so how do I reset them?

Comment: Never mind, a clean did the trick.

Comment: I just cleaned the project and then rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a solution to this kind of problem: select your project, go to **Build** menu and select **Clean Solution**. Then build it again.